# Removing single quotes in struts2

Tags: struts2, string-formatting

I have the following code in my JSP.

```
<td style="text-align:center;"><s:property value="accountCode"/></td>
```

when i get the values from the back-end, i am passing it with the single quotes(eg. '1234'). However, when i display it, i want to remove these quotes and display just the number.(eg.1234). How do i do this?

I tried `<s:property value="accountCode.replace('\'','')"/> and <s:property value="accountCode.replaceAll('\'','')"/>,` but it does not work!(Did not show me the value itself!)

Comment: Are you sending `accountCode` value as `'1234'` from the server? Why don't you handle it on server?

Comment: @HashimR I am sending it via quotes to write it to csv that way. I need to display the same thing on the screen but without the quotes

Comment: Well you can append `''` before writing it to csv. No?

Comment: Sadly, i am unable to do that because of the way the code is written :(

Comment: Hmmm I recommend you to fix your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using replaceAll method is OK, then 
`<s:property value="accountCode.replaceAll('\\'', '')" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `escapeJavaScript` attribute of the tag:

`<s:property value="accountCode" escapeJavaScript="true"/>`

**EDIT**:

Use this:

```
<s:property value="accountCode.replaceAll('\'','')" />
```

Comment: this is the value i am getting when i use it
`\'1234\'`

Comment: Use this: `<s:property value="accountCode.replaceAll('\'','')" />`

Comment: I did try that. Mentioned the same in the query too. the value refuses to display.